# Is there a term that designates a "straight mapping" function?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Suppose I have two sets $A = \{A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4\}$, and $B = \{1,2,3,4\}$. I can create a bijection mapping between $A$ and $B$, but is there a term that implies that the mapping itself doesn't matter? For example, I can map $A_1 \mapsto 1$, $A_2 \mapsto 2$, and so on. However, I can also do $A_1 \mapsto 2$, $A_2 \mapsto 1$, ... etc. As long as the bijective property is satisfied, this seems valid. Though, I want to know if there is a term for saying whether how the mapping is defined matters or not. I'm self-defining "straight mapping" as a mapping that goes directly from left to right if we pictorially represent $A$ and $B$ (i.e., imagine we draw $A$ and $B$ as circles with each member of the set vertically and we draw an arrow from each element in $A$ to each element in $B$). I'll also define a "cross mapping" as a bijection that is *not* a straight mapping.

In essence, are there terms for this sort of thing or this property of a function? I haven't taken an abstract algebra class, so I wouldn't be sure one way or the other.

Comment: I think this only makes sense if A and B have an ordering to them, in which case it's an "order preserving map".

Comment: Note that $\{A,B\}$ literally is the same thing as $\{B,A\}$ - a *particular way of describing* a set may indicate a preferred ordering, but sets per se do not come equipped with an order. (If they do, they're not *just* sets but "linear orders" or something similar, in the same way that a group isn't just its underlying set.)

Comment: What you describe as a "straight mapping" can be thought of being an "isomorphism".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me expand on the comments, which give the right approach. When you write $A = \{A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4\}$, you implicitly define a [linear order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) (also called *total order*) on the set $A$, namely $A_1 < A_2 < A_3 < A_4$. You also implicitly define a linear order when you "pictorially represent $A$ vertically".
What you call a *straight mapping* is called an [order-preserving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_theory#Functions_between_orders) (or *monotone*) map in mathematics.

Now your question raises an interesting issue. The [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) of a finite set is just the number of its elements, but this notion can be extended to infinite sets as well. In particular, two sets $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality if there exists a bijection from $A$ to $B$. When you want to prove that two sets have the same cardinality, finding a bijection is enough and the choice of the bijection is irrelevant. For instance, one can show that $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb Z$ have the same cardinality.

What happens now if you consider linearly ordered sets instead of sets?
Two linearly ordered sets $(A,<)$ and $(B,<)$ are said to have the *same order type* if there is an order preserving bijection from $A$ to $B$.
This makes a huge difference with the definition of cardinals.
For instance, $(\Bbb N, <)$ and $(\Bbb Z, <)$ **do not have** the same order type, as there is no order-preserving bijection between them.

At the risk of confusing you even more, let me add a last remark. If two linearly ordered sets have the order type, then they have the same cardinal. Moreover, if two **finite** linearly ordered sets $(A,<)$ and $(B,<)$ have the same cardinal, then they have the same the order type. In other words, if there is a bijection from $A$ to $B$, then there is always an order-preserving bijection between them (a non-trivial fact). But this is not true if $A$ and $B$ are infinite, like $(\Bbb N, <)$ and $(\Bbb Z, <)$.